# More than 20 minutes to start Spring application. How to reduce it?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat7

I'm maintaining an old Spring project and it's startup time is very long. The app is running under Tomcat 7 and using Hibernate 4.3 + PostgreSQL 9.5. [This is](http://pastebin.com/MmEWdvfv) the log from IntelliJ IDEA that is being written on app start (uploaded to Pastebin due to SO post length limitations). Notice that time gap between 3rd and 2nd lines from the bottom. It seems that nothing is happening during that time. I've tried to set all log levels to `TRACE` but still haven't seen any other output to log. The question is how can I reduce the startup time? This is the things I've already tried:

- set `default-lazy-init=true` on the main context configuration file;
- set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `none` on the persistance config;
- set `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` to `false` on the persistance config.

Non of them produced any measurable results. What else can I try? At least how can I understand what is happening during all this time?

Comment: Maybe you are having an internet speed issue(firewall, slow internet speed) between your application and remote DB server. Also, check your CPU and RAM usage done by tomcat process.

Comment: This is good point. I'll try to monitor network and CPU activity during deploy.

Comment: Do a CPU profile, or take a few thread dumps during, or attach a debugger and pause the running threads and see what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to copy the `.war` file of your application to the `webapps` folder and let tomcat do the deployment, it is quicker and will save your time.
Tomcat supports `hot deployment`.  Tomcat monitors the deployment directory for changes, so you can just copy the `.war` file into that directory, and the server will `undeploy/redeploy`.

You can write a script using `ANT` to automate the deployment process.

Comment: I think that IDEA basically does the same thing on deploy.

Comment: Try it first, let's see the outcome.